# add Show and hide class using JS in PWA area

Tags: javascript, css, progressive-web-apps

I have PWA button which appears only when **beforeinstallprompt** fires and add class **available**, before that, display is none.

I want one dummy button which should be **display block** but when beforeinstallprompt fires, dummy button should be **display none**.

I could not add the JS functionality to do the same.
My Div:

```
<button class="btnApp"> PWA Button </button>
<button class="dummy"> Dummy Button </button>
```

My CSS:

```
button.mybtn {
    display: none;
}
button.mybtn.available {
    display: block;
}
```

My JS:

```
"serviceWorker" in navigator && (navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js", {
    scope: "/"
}), function() {
    "use strict";
    var e = function(e) {
        var t, n = function() {
            t && (t.prompt(), t.userChoice.then((function(n) {
                t = null, ga("send", "event", "install", "install", n), e.classList.remove("available")
            })).catch((function() {
                t = null, ga("send", "event", "error", "error"), e.classList.remove("available")
            })))
        };
        window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (function(n) {
            return t = n, ga("send", "event", "available", "available"), e.classList.add("available"), !1
        })), window.addEventListener("appinstalled", (function() {
            document.body.querySelector(".btnApp").style.display = "none", t = null, ga("send", "event", "installed", "installed"), e.classList.remove("available")
        })), e.addEventListener("click", n.bind(this)), e.addEventListener("touchend", n.bind(this))
    };
    window.addEventListener("load", (function() {
        var t = document.body.querySelector(".btnApp");
        new e(t)
    }))
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question but I think what you are asking is how to enable and disable elements from your script file;
To do that, you can do something such as

```
document.getElementById("btnApp").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("btnApp").style.display = "block";
```

to disable and enable elements respectively. Let me know if this didn't answer your question

Comment: for the class btnApp, it is good. I want to add a class 'dummyavailable' for dummy button which has class name 'dummy' when beforeinstallprompts fire, you can see my JS and help me using that.

Comment: so doing something such as 
document.getElementById("ID").className = "button.mybtn.available ";
to change the div element to another class?

Comment: document.getElementById("dummy").style.display = "none";
 can you integrate this in beforeinstallprompts function?

Comment: if you are hiding the element anyways I would do- document.getElementById("dummy").style.display = "none"; -instead to just have it not appear until the display type is changed

Comment: OK please customize that

Comment: it should already be customized; To start make sure your button has it's display set to none in either the css or html. Now let's say your beforeinstallprompts runs after a button and you want to show the dummy button. You can add to either your onclick or the beforeinstall- document.getElementById("dummy").style.display = "block"; -assuming the element you are toggling on is the dummy button.